# Run qml application in VScode

Tags: qt, visual-studio-code, qml

I have a simple sample QML app that runs perfectly when using QTcreator. When I open the same project in VScode, I am getting:

```
..../main.qml:1:module "QtQuick" version 2.15 is not installed
```

this comes from the first line in my code: `import QtQuick 2.15`

How do I fix this to make it work in VScode?. I am using [Felgo](https://blog.felgo.com/develop-qt-quick-apps-with-visual-studio-code-qml-extension) to run the QML app.

Using Linux machine, Ubuntu 20.04.

I have tried editing the `c_cpp_properties.json` file and add the path to qt5 folder.

No luck so far.

Comment: You should set the environment variable `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` correctly inside launch.json

Comment: @Amfasis im afraid that did not work

Comment: Can you actually run the program outside vscode, just in terminal? Possibly you can find some cause by using `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS`

Comment: Do you use some QML plugin? Didi you check [this](https://blog.felgo.com/develop-qt-quick-apps-with-visual-studio-code-qml-extension) doc?

Comment: @folibis yes that was my main guide to make it work, but not working so far